# Help with page styling

Tags: css, page-layout

I have the following image being placed at the top of a page.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <div>
        <div>
            <img src="Images/top.png" width="100%" height="115px" alt="top.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The problem is there is a bit of padding that is appearing to the left, top, right, and bottom of the image. I don't want that padding there. In other words, I want the image top be flush with the left and top of the page, and for it to stretch across the width of the page. How can I achieve this with a style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers' default styles give the body element a padding, and some give it a margin.  You'll need to remove both in order for the image to be flush against the viewport in all browsers.

```
    body { margin: 0; border: 0 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use CSS reset rules to reset browser styles, then build from there. I use http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/

Comment: You need to remember that when using a reset like that will zero out all of the elements on a page, not just the one that you're working with. If you're starting out with a fresh creation, this fine, but if you're working with an established site, this could lead to more issues. Use carefully.

Comment: This zeroes out the *default* values for all elements. It does not clear any CSS you have already written. Remember -- your site's CSS is building off of _something_, and if it isn't built on a reset, then it's built on each browser's default styles, leading to unpredictability.

Comment: I shouldn't need to reset it. I have only one CSS link, and the CSS file itself only has *body {background-color: #FFFFCC;}*

Answer (score 0):

```
<img style="display: block; padding: 0; margin: 0;" ... />
```

However if its an image that is essentially a decoratin of somesort (ie. not "content" or linked to another page) i prefer to use it as a background image in the parent element.

For example

#pseudo-image {height: 100px; width: 200px; background: transparent url(path/to/image) scroll no-repeat top left;}

Of course doing it this way you are limited to displaying the image at its actual size and you have to set the div to those same dimensions or larger.

Comment: Actually using an image as the background of a item or even the page might be easier to control than dropping in an img tag.

Comment: Actually, I tried to use it as a background-image in the div tag, but I was unable to get it to stretch across the screen. It would just repeat itself, which I can't have. However, if I use the img tag then it will stretch as I want it to.

Comment: Well you have to set it not to repeat. see revised answer above for example.

Comment: Well, doing so will stop the image from repeating, but it won't **stretch** it to the actual width of the browser window, which is really what I need it to do.